# Python Classes ( AttributeError: '' object has no attribute '')

Tags: python, class, object, instance

Having trouble understanding the problem in my code, new to classes (generally python too, so sorry if I name things wrong). I receive this error:

I think my code is too long winded to include in here, so I made a simplified version to test the concept below.

The question is, **how can I create a new self object**  "self4"? Which would then be available to other functions within the class. Currently I get this error.

> AttributeError: 'className' object has no attribute 'self4'

```
class className(object):

   def __init__(self, self1=1,self2=2,self3=3):
        self.self1=self1
        self.self2=self2
        self.self3=self3

   def evaluate(self, self5):
        print className.func1(self) + className.func2(self)
        self.self5=self5
        print className.func1(self)

   def func1(self):
       return self.self1 + self.self5

   def func2(self):
       self.self4 = self.self1+self.self2+self.self3
       return self.self4
```

filename `tester.py`

```
import tester.py

mst=tester.className()

mst.evaluate()
```

Comment: Why don't you call `self.func2()` in `__init__` ?

Comment: I've added how I call this code. I want to be able to call evaluate for different conditions e.g. self1=4 and self1 = 3.

Comment: I just ran the code in your question and it works fine....it prints 7 6. The question is not valid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
Your code works fine!
What is the Problem?

I still think it is better to move `self4` into the init!

**Original**
I think the most logical thing would be to define `self4` on init:

```
class className(object):
    def __init__(self, self1=1, self2=2, self3=3):
        self.self1 = self1
        self.self2 = self2
        self.self3 = self3
        self.self4 = None

   #rest of class
```

Comment: Indeed it does, tried it right now. So there is basically no error and therefore no question?!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still has this issue: you get this error when your indentation is goofed.To fix the asked question above, you just have to add a space before the last two functions definitions, that is;

```
class className(object):
    

    def __init__(self, self1=1,self2=2,self3=3):
        self.self1=self1
        self.self2=self2
        self.self3=self3

    def evaluate(self, self5):
        
        print className.func1(self) + className.func2(self)
        self.self5=self5
        print className.func1(self)

    def func1(self):
        return self.self1 + self.self5

    def func2(self):
        self.self4 = self.self1+self.self2+self.self3
        return self.self4
```

just make sure they all have similar indentation, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else ever gets this error and it is not an indentation problem, the error can also occur if you accidentally wrote `;` Instead of `:` for the type annotation:

```
>>> class Example:
...     def __init__(self, var: str) -> None:
...         self.var; str = var
... 
>>> Example('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `self4` in method.